# Unresolved reference for databinding after upgrading to android studio 4.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-4.0

I'm getting `Unresolved reference: databinding"` and `"Unresolved reference: ActivityHomeBinding"` even all resources (string, color etc.) are showing `Unresolved reference` in XML layouts. This is happening after upgrading the android studio to `4.0`. Tried a lot but no luck. Other projects are working well which are not using databinding. Again downgrading the android studio to `3.6` and it's working perfectly. I have used the following versions:

- Android Studio 4.0, Android Gradle Plugin Version: 4.0.0 and Gradle Version 6.1.1 [Not working]
- Android Studio 4.0, Android Gradle Plugin Version: 3.5.3 and Gradle Version 5.4.1 [Not working]
- Android Studio 3.6, Android Gradle Plugin Version: 3.5.3 and Gradle Version 5.4.1 [Working]